# elastic: Error 400 (Bad Request): failed to execute script [type=illegal_argument_exception]

Tags: elasticsearch, go

Using **gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5**
for adding a field to a document in elasticsearch 
Code:

```
script := elastic.NewScript(`ctx._source.new_field += params.vijay`).Param("vijay", "kumar").p
                //script := elastic.NewScript("ctx._source.retweets += params.num").Param("num", 1)
                fmt.Println("script", script)
                update, err := client.Update().Index("idx001").Type("sdoc").Id(t.Docid).Script(script).Do(ctx)
                if err != nil {
                    // Handle error
                    panic(err)
                }
                fmt.Println("result is", update.Result)
```

And the result got is(here i am printing the script formed also)

**script &{ctx._source.new_field += params.vijay   map[vijay:kumar]}
panic: elastic: Error 400 (Bad Request): failed to execute script [type=illegal_argument_exception]**

Expected the field **vijay** to be added into elasticsearch with the value **kumar**